# delete row from wordpress custom table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to read data from wordpress custom table. I created table and got data from it. Now I need to create link for every row from table and when I click on link it should delete only one row.

```
global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customtable';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
    $check = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    echo '<div class="col-lg-2">';
foreach ($check as $loc){
        echo $loc->row1;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '<br>';

    }

    echo '</div>';
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['delete'] ))
{
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name, [ 'id' => $loc->id] );
}
```

Link is working but I can't delete specific row.

I tried creating function delete

```
function delete($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customtable';
     $wpdb->delete( $table_name, [ 'id' => $id] );

}
```

and then outside of foreach loop I defined

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])){
        $this->delete($loc->id);

    }
```

but again only last row is deleted.

Comment: is the wp_debug true? what error does it say?

Comment: wp debug is true
Delete link is generated above every row but when I click on any link it deletes last row. No errors

Comment: in that case you should send the id of the row that you want to delete with the submit because it seems it assigns the last row in your database

Comment: I tried it. I created function delete($id) and then called $wpdb->delete($table_name, ['id' => $id ] ); and called function in isset statement $this->delete($loc->id); but still same thing. It deletes only last row.

Comment: have you tried echoing the id inside the isset?

Comment: if I echo $loc->id after delete statement (called directly in isset or called from function) it echo id of last row in table and deletes it. Only if I put isset inside foreach loop it deletes entire table

Comment: add a value to the existing form. Let the value be an ID
When the request is passed gather that ID with the request and delete it

Comment: I added $id=$loc->id; inside foreach loop.
Then I added if( isset( $_REQUEST[$id] ))
{
            $id = $_REQUEST[$id];
            $wpdb->delete( $table_name, [ 'id' => $id] );
            echo $id;
}
outside of the loop. Now nothing happens. Nothing is deleted

Comment: I'm guessing it's because no id has been passed. Sorry it's a bit hard helping with the code when I can't test it and not to mention this is wordpress so double trouble

Comment: Yes, I understand everything. I was tried 100 combinations before posting question but no luck. Hope someone else will know. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I came up to this solution. If I call delete link inside foreach loop it will delete entire table and if I call it outside it deletes only last row.
I made php script inside plugin folder and posted id into it.

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$my_url = explode('wp-content' , $url); 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$my_url[0];
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['ID'])){
$id = $_REQUEST['ID'];
delete_row($id);

}

function delete_row($id){
    global $wpdb;
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customtable';
     $wpdb->query( 
 $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
            DELETE FROM $table_name
     WHERE id = %d",
        $id
    )
);
}
```

and inside function that reads all data from database and generates delete link:

```
foreach ($check as $loc){
        echo $loc->location;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<a name="delete" href="'.$dir.'delete_loc.php?ID=' . $loc->id . '">delete</a>';
        echo '<br>';

    }
```